# es6 import from underscore

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I wanted to double check to make sure I understand imports enough to know if it is ok to do `import {_.identity} from 'underscore'` opposed to `import _ from 'underscore'`? That is the only use of underscore if the particular file.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Looks like you're very close!

There are a few ways to do this.

IMO the cleanest way to do this goes like this:

```
import { map, reduce, somethingElse } from 'underscore'
```

Allowing you to call those methods as so:

```
map(things, thing => {
    ...
})
```

The '{ map, reduce } = ...' part is es6s destructuring assignment.
See [the Mozilla docs page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) for more details on this!

Another way would be to do:

```
import map from 'underscore/map'
import reduce from 'underscore/reduce'
```

Personally, I'm not a big fan of this since it can start being a bit more cumbersome as more methods are pulled in but it does have one slight advantage, you can name the reference as you like:

```
import mappy from 'underscore/map'
import reducerify from 'underscore/reduce'
```

Though I wouldn't advise using those names!

Comment: Cool, so I just leave out the `_.` ?

Comment: I would be careful with naming imports from underscore/lodash as functions like map and reduce already have a JS implementation, which creates a collision. It's usually better to name them something like _map, _reduce, or perhaps something odd like @Spen suggested.

Answer (score 3):

Import: `import * as _ from 'underscore'`

https://underscorejs.org/#map

Example:

```
_.map(things, thing => {
    ...
})
```